# Is it possible to prove $\exists a(b + a = b) \vdash \exists a(a + a = a)$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I can prove the following:

$$\exists a\forall b(b + a = b) \vdash \exists a(a + a = a)$$

as shown below:

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$
$\fitch {
   1. \qquad \exists a\forall b(b + a = b) \qquad (A)
}{
   \fitch {
      2. \qquad \forall b(b + c = b) \qquad (A)
   }{
      3. \qquad c + c = c \qquad (\forall E: 2) \\
      4. \qquad \exists a(a + a = a) \qquad (\exists I: 3)
   } \\
   5. \qquad \exists a(a + a = a) \qquad (\exists E: 1, 2-4)
}$

but I don't know how to prove $\exists a(b + a = b) \vdash \exists a(a + a = a)$.  The two sequents are similar, except that I guess the second one is a bit weaker, but I would have thought it would be provable as well.  The attempts I have made are as follows:

$\fitch {
   1. \qquad \exists a(b + a = b) \qquad (A)
}{
   \fitch {
      2. \qquad (b + b = b) \qquad (A)
   }{
      3. \qquad \exists a(a + a = a) \qquad (\exists I: 2)
   } \\
   4. \qquad \exists a(a + a = a) \qquad (\exists E: 1, 2-3)
}$

The final line is an invalid inference, since the term used in the substitution on line 2 ($b$) is present in an undischarged assumption on line 1, violating the $\exists E$ rule.  This is a consequence of using a term that already existed in the first assumption.  So, I tried using a new variable as follows:

$\fitch {
   1. \qquad \exists a(b + a = b) \qquad (A)
}{
   \fitch {
      2. \qquad (b + c = b) \qquad (A)
   }{
      3. \qquad \exists c(c + c = c) \qquad (\exists I: 2)
   } \\
   4. \qquad \exists c(c + c = c) \qquad (\exists E: 1, 2-3)
}$

Of course, the final line is also invalid here because $c$ is present in an undischarged assumption (line 2).

In summary, I have had no luck trying to prove this sequent.  It seems like this sequent is true, since if there exists an $a$ such that $b + a = b$ (we know there is from experience: $a = 0$), then there exists an $a$ such that $a + a = a$ (which we also know from experience is true: $a = 0$).  What mistake am I making?

**EDIT**: I think perhaps my flaw here is that I am using my intuition of what addition means in arithmetic, and placing this meaning on the function symbol +, which has no meaning in this context.  If I was to remove these and replace with a notation $f(a,b)$ instead, it may not be true that $\exists a(f(b,a) = b) \vdash \exists a(f(a,a) = a)$ for all functions $f$.  I'm just trying to think of a counterexample function where this does not hold for $f$.

Comment: IMO, the mistake is that you are trying to prove it "by logic alone", but you have in mind an arithmetical interpretation. In order to prove it, you have to use Peano's axioms.

Comment: You have to find a suitable counterexample to the corresponding: $\forall x \exists y (f(x,y)=x), \exists z (f(z,z)=z)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I just come to the same conclusion!  See the edits.

Comment: Exponentiation would be a counterexample, am I correct?  $x^1 = x$, satisfying the premise, but there is no $x$ such that $x^x = x$.

Comment: @esotechnica Doesn't $x=1$ satisfy $x^x=x$?

Comment: Example: define $x\circ y=y-1.$ Then $b\circ(b+1)=b$ but $a\circ a=a-1\ne a.$

Comment: @bof, of course, how stupid of me!  And yes, while the function you defined above I guess technically meets the criteria, it could really be defined as a  'unary' function as it only depends on one term.  I'm trying to think of one where the definition uses both terms.

Comment: Define $x\circ y=\frac{x+y}2-1.$ Then $b\circ(b+2)=b$ and $a\circ a=a-1\ne a.$

Comment: @bof nice one, thanks